# Convert XSD to TypeScript

Tags: xml, typescript, xsd, schema

I found this [tool](https://github.com/charto/cxsd). CXSD

On their documentation: cxsd is a streaming XSD parser and XML parser generator for Node.js and (optionally but highly recommended) TypeScript.
This is exactly what I need, so I follow their documentation and start to execute commands.

I have a problem when I try to execute this command:
npm run cxsd file:///C:/XSDtoTypeScript/Flexinova.RBF.LI.V1.xsd

Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid URI "file:///C:/XSDtoTypeScript/Flexinova.RBF.LI.V1.xsd"

But when I try to open this from a browser, it opens normally. I don't know why URI is invalid? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

•   Run command: **npm install http-server -g**

•   Open Node.js command prompt as administrator and raise your file on localhost using following command: **http-server C:\XSDtoTypeScript**

•   Now try to open your xsd which is in this folder. 
Example: http://localhost:8080/Flexinova.RBF.LI.V1.xsd

Now use the command: **npm run cxsd http://localhost:8080/Flexinova.RBF.LI.V1.xsd**
You are done

Answer (score 0):

How to run in 2024:

The cxsd package only works with Node.js 12.

But it looks like it works with [Bun](https://bun.sh), so you can simply call it with
bunx: bunx cxsd http://your-xsd-file.xsd

Note that you may need to upload your XSD file to some https server (see previous response on how to make a quick http server) on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using these steps:

1. Create a package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "http-server",
    "convert": "cxsd"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cxsd": "^0.1.1",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1"
  }
}
```

2. Running a server to share local files via http:

```
nvm install v12
npm run dev
```

3. Run the convertor in a separate tab:

```
nvm use v12
npm run convert http://localhost:8080/file.xsd
```